# Set restrictions for user input email address

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I want put a restriction so that the user inputted email address wont be accepted if it has an exclamation point.

Perhaps I change type to "email" in 4th line?

```
<label class="control-label" for="emailAddr1">
<span class="required">*</span> Email Address
</label>

<form:input path="emailAddr" type="text" id="emailAddr1" cssClass="form-control" maxlength="50"/>

<span class="${emailHasBindError ? "glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" : ""}"></span>

<form:errors path="emailAddr" cssClass="required" element="span">
</form:errors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should change the type to email to implement the basic HTML email validation. You can see what it validates in [the HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address). The same information is also available [at MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#validation).

But this validation will allow exclamation marks in the first part before the "@". So if you want that extra validation you need to implement it using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Thank you for the resources, I am unclear in how to implement a regular expression here that will omit the "!". What would you suggest

Comment: You need to build one that only accepts letters and numbers, for example. In the link in the answer, you have all the information about how to work with regex in JavaScript.